# Angular 1.5 - Unable to run in local server SB-Admin-Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate a customized version of https://github.com/start-angular/sb-admin-angular in my nginx server for production. However it runs only when I npm start from my local machine. Is there any additional configurations that I need to configure for this.

Answer (score 0):

Running grunt serve:dist --force solve my problem :)